# How to only allow once occurance of a character in a row of cells

Tags: excel

[image]

As you can see in the image above I have an example of characters which can be entered. However in that row 'A' can only be entered once. How can I implement this rule?

Answer (score 2):

Use data validation on the row with this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(1:1,A1)=1
```

change `1:1` as required for the row you need.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake with the original post, I meant to say A can only be entered in once.

Comment: @DatBundah just change `A1` to `"A"` and it will do that

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Data Validation.

- Select the complete row say Row 1
- In the `Data` Menu, click `Data Validation` in `Data Tools` Group
- Under `Settings` tab, select `Custom` in `Allow` drop down list
- In the `Formula` box, enter `=COUNTIF(1:1,A1)=1` and click `OK` (in the formula 1 represents the `Row 1`)

See the image below:

[image]

If you'll try to enter already existing character then the following message will pop up.

[image]

If you specifically want only letter "A" not to repeat then change the formula to `=COUNTIF(1:1,"A")=1`

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake with the original post, I meant to say A can only be entered in once.

Comment: @DatBundah - If you specifically want only letter "A" not to repeat then change the formula to `=COUNTIF(1:1,"A")=1`. I've already mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: I tried that but when I try to enter in a different character e.g. '"R" I get an error message

Comment: Like the ones you have shown in the second screen shot

Comment: @DatBundah - See the file [here](http://www.filedropper.com/conditionalformating).